# unserialize() function does not work on a variable from the MySQL table on new server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, string, serialization

We just switched our website over to a new server. There is a part of my PHP software that pulls out a serialized data value from the MySQL table, and puts it into a variable, and then it's supposed to unserialize().

I never had this issue on any other servers (and this exact code is used on many different servers..), but I'm getting an issue where the value fails to unserialize - it returns false (blank).

HOWEVER, if I copy the exact value, put it into another $var, and then unserialize($var) it, it works perfectly fine into an array... they are the exact same values. One works, the other doesn't.

Check out the following link to visualize what I mean..

http://paulmasoumi.com/admin/test.php

And the PHP code on this page is:

```
<?
include 'start.php';

$var = 'a:8:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:11:"New Listing";i:2;s:11:"Just Listed";i:3;s:9:"New Price";i:4;s:17:"Exclusive Listing";i:5;s:12:"Just Reduced";i:6;s:31:"Great Price!;Showroom Condition";i:7;s:42:"Featured In;Dream Homes of Canada Magazine";}';


echo 'Echoing $var:<br />';
echo $var;
echo '<br />';


echo 'Echoing $settings[\'remarksdisplay\'] retrieved from mysql database field:<br />';
echo $settings['remarksdisplay'];
echo '<br />';

echo '<br />';

echo 'When you run print_r(unserialize($var)):<br />';
print_r(unserialize($var));
echo '<br />';

echo 'When you run print_r(unserialize($settings[\'remarksdisplay\'])):<br />';
print_r(unserialize($settings['remarksdisplay']));

echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

echo 'When you run IF statement to see if $settings[\'remarksdisplay\']==$var:<br />';
if($settings['remarksdisplay']==$var) {echo "EQUAL";} else {echo 'not equal';}
?>
```

I've also checked the server settings regarding the serialize() and unserialize() functions...

Check out these two settings:
http://www.paulmasoumi.com/admin/phpinfo.php
http://demo.brixwork.com/admin/phpinfo.php

Settings involving serialization of strings, magic quotes etc. are all identical.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings are not identical. Viewing the source of your page the one coming out of the database has a linebreak:

```
a:8:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:11:"New Listing";i:2;s:11:"Just Listed";i:3;s:9:"New Price";i:4;s:17:"Exclusive Listing";i:5;s:12:"Just Reduced";i:6;s:31:"Great 
Price!;Showroom Condition";i:7;s:42:"Featured In;Dream Homes of Canada Magazine";
```

As you can see after Great. But, it should handle the new line characters just fine. When I copied the database serialized string and tried to unserialize it I received a:

> PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 176 of 234 bytes in php shell code on line 1

Which means something funky is happening, not sure what. I am going to keep digging, but just posting what I found out. If you want a true test, however, add a newline after Great.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$var = 'a:8:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:11:"New Listing";i:2;s:11:"Just Listed";i:3;s:9:"New Price";i:4;s:17:"Exclusive Listing";i:5;s:12:"Just Reduced";i:6;s:31:"Great' . "\n" .  
'Price!;Showroom Condition";i:7;s:42:"Featured In;Dream Homes of Canada Magazine";}';

$settings['remarksdisplay'] = 'a:8:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:11:"New Listing";i:2;s:11:"Just Listed";i:3;s:9:"New Price";i:4;s:17:"Exclusive Listing";i:5;s:12:"Just Reduced";i:6;s:31:"Great
Price!;Showroom Condition";i:7;s:42:"Featured In;Dream Homes of Canada Magazine";}';

echo 'Echoing $var:' . PHP_EOL;
echo $var;
echo "\n\n";


echo 'Echoing $settings[\'remarksdisplay\'] retrieved from mysql database field:' . PHP_EOL;
echo $settings['remarksdisplay'];

echo "\n\n";

echo 'When you run print_r(unserialize($var)):' . PHP_EOL;
print_r(unserialize($var));
echo "\n";

echo 'When you run print_r(unserialize($settings[\'remarksdisplay\'])):' . PHP_EOL;
print_r(unserialize($settings['remarksdisplay']));

echo "\n\n";

echo 'When you run IF statement to see if $settings[\'remarksdisplay\']==$var:' . PHP_EOL;
if($settings['remarksdisplay']==$var) {echo "EQUAL";} else {echo 'not equal';}
echo PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Sorry, I changed the Linebreaks to NewLine characters cause I tested it in CLI. The above code has the extra space **after Great** removed and it works just fine.

So what was happening was basically that extra space threw off the count, as you can see the s:XX the number indicates how long the string is, that extra space made it 32 instead of 31 for the "Great Price" statement, since serialize needs to be accurate, it was throwing a Notice error, which most people do not show and why there were no errors coming through.

Comment: Oh darn! You're right. There is a linebreak that only shows when I apply the nl2br function... F*ck!!! How did this happen? The database transfer was supposed to be seamless!

Comment: Well, it is not necessarily the line break. It should work fine with the linebreak. The real issue is before the line break there is an extra whitespace. Once you remove that it should work. (See updated Test)

Comment: Turns out that wasn't the only extra line-break added. When I copy-pasted the values from phpmyadmin to my textedit app, it showed extra linebreaks on many of the serialized values which should NOT have the extra breaks!! It wasn't the only issue - the new web hosts, upon transfer, messed up a lot of things, including putting 3 duplicate lines on my products table, which is a HUGE pain in the butt.

Comment: Thanks though, you basically solved my problem.. now the eternal labour of tracking down all the issues and correcting it begins... MySQL here i come.

Comment: I guess I should start a new thread on "How on earth does a simple MySQL data transfer from one server to another add a lot of extra linebreaks all over the place, generate duplicate rows with identical id fields (which are supposed to be unique/primary)??"

Answer (score 1):

Use substr to remove quotes like

```
$str = substr( $data['str'], 1, -1 );
```

and then unserialize your data.

***reason is mysql return quoted string***

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, maybe the database returns some kind of object that doesn't play well with unserialize? Try:

```
$str = (string) $settings['remarksdisplay'];
print_r(unserialize($str));
```